# Get a specific list of users excluding few users

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 2 table users and user_request

user

```
id  name
1    U1
2    U2
3    U3
4    U4
5    U5
```

user_request

```
id   userid  name   status
1      1      U1    rejected
2      3      U3    rejected
```

I need list of users from user table but those users should not be there which are present in user_request table

So according to above example i need the following list of users

```
U2
U4
U5
```

From the user table i am using the following code to fetch the result

```
$query = $this->db->get('user');
return $query->result();
```

From the user_request table i am using the following code to fetch the result

```
$this->db->where('status','rejected');
$query = $this->db->get('user_request');
return $query->result();
```

Can anyone please help me to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple query using `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT name FROM user WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT userid FROM user_request)
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0067/1)

---

**UPDATE:** For Codeigniter:

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('user');
$this->db->where('`id` NOT IN (SELECT `userid` FROM `user_request`)', NULL, FALSE);
```

Comment: i wish to use the given format (as given in post ) of code only, so in this format i tried using NOT IN but was not able to use it, i got an error saying invalid format (I am using codeigniter framework)

Comment: If possible can you use `$this->db->query()`?

Comment: your code didn't had the status and was giving few errors so i reformed it a bit and used the following code 

$this->db->where('`id` NOT IN (SELECT `userid` FROM `user_request` where `status`!=`rejected`)', NULL, FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get('user');
return $query->result();

Comment: i am still not getting the result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131465/discussion-between-thamilan-and-user3732711).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a join:

```
$this->db->select('name');
$this->db->from('user');
$this->db->join('user_request', 'user.id = user_request.userid');
$this->db->where('status !=','rejected');
return $this->db->get();
```

Comment: didnt work, giving  Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::table()  error

Comment: what framework are you using ? I thought it was laravel

Comment: i am getting a blank array

Comment: SELECT `name` FROM `user` JOIN `user_request` ON `user`.`id` = `user_request`.`userid` WHERE `status` != 'rejected'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131468/discussion-between-meda-and-user3732711).

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the id from first table, fetch the userid from second table. remove the common values from the 2 arrays and you will get the desired result

```
  $this->db->select('id');
    $query = $this->db->get('user');
    $first = $query->result();
    foreach ($first as $key) 
        {
            $user_one = $key->id;
            $first_array[] = $user_one;
        }

    $this->db->where('status','rejected');
    $query_two = $this->db->get('user_request');
    $two = $query_two->result();

    foreach ($two as $value) 
        {
            $userid_two = $value->userid;
            $second_array[] = $userid_two;
        }

    $arr_1 = array_diff($first_array, $second_array);

    $std = array();
    foreach ($arr_1 as  $value) 
        {

            $this->db->where('id',$value);
            $main_query = $this->db->get('user');
            $main = $main_query->result();
            $std = array_merge($std,$main);
        }

    return $std;
```